# Dividing objects as innerHtml into different html elements by position parameters

Tags: javascript, html

Could you please steer me towards an elegant solution of dividing sorted array of objects into multiple HTML elements based on the objects' position attributes?

Without the need of the dividing the object I would just use the map function to transform the data to its HTML representation:

```
const htmlArray = myData.map(myObject => {
    const myObjectHtml =
        `<li>
            <h2>${myObject._title}</h2>
            <p>${myObject._text}</p>
        </li>`;
    return myObjectHtml;
});

const allInOne = htmlArray.join('');
const column = document.querySelector('#col');
column.innerHTML = allInOne;
```

I have already written the sorting function based on the desired positions of objects, where

• `x` is should denote the column number

• `y` determines the order of the objects within each of the columns.

```
myData.sort(function compare(a, b) {
    if (a._x < b._x) return -1;
    else if (a._x > b._x) return 1;
    else {
        if (a._y < b._y) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
});
```

**But I would like to divide them - already sorted ascending by `x` and `y` - into multiple columns based on the `x` possibly using some other plain JavaScript *elegant* functions.**

Thank you.

**Edit:** Just to clear up - I am able to sort the objects by the desired attribute of column number (`x`) and also iterate - with the map function - through the whole array and map each object to its HTML representation, but how do I also split it effectively into groups by the `x`? My goal is to make the column contain only the HTML of the matching data objects.

I am hoping, there is a way to map it onto HTML and also split into different HTML chunks. Otherwise I guess I would probably need to go through the array with a for cycle to separate each object into a different HTML chunk.

Comment: 1. *"...objects into multiple HTML elements **based on** the objects' position attributes?"* 2. *"...already written the sorting function **based on** the desired positions of objects, "* 3, *"into multiple columns **based on** the x possibly using some other plain JavaScript elegant functions"* **1.** and  **3.** is the same question? **2.** means you already resolved your issue? Everything is **based on** something but it isn't very apparent to what exactly is this *thing* is ***based on***?

Comment: Yes and no. Sorting occurs only within the whole array. I would like to split it based on the `x` then in separate HTML elements as the innerHtml attribute.